# Deduce simple formula of collisional broadening for $\Delta \lambda$

Tags: laser, wavelength

The [German Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druckverbreiterung) states that the broadened wavelength can be given by:

$$\Delta \lambda \approx \dfrac{\lambda^2}{\pi\,c\,\Delta t}$$

with $\Delta t$ as mean collision time given by $\Delta t = l/v$

Might someone be so inclined to explain where this comes from?